# writing an object to disk in R through C++ vs. fst

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I was inspired by the `fst` package to try to write a C++ function to quickly serialize some data structures I have in R to disk.

But I am having trouble achieving the same write speed even on very simple objects.  The code below is a simple example of writing a large 1 GB vector to disk.

Using custom C++ code, I achieve a write speed of 135 MB/s, which is the limit of my disk according to CrystalBench.

On the same data, `write_fst` achieves a write speed of 223 MB/s, which seems impossible since my disk can't write that fast.  (Note, I am using `fst::threads_fst(1)` and `compress=0` settings, and the files have the same data size.)

What am I missing?

How can I get the C++ function to write to disk faster?

C++ Code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(SEXP x) {
  char* d = reinterpret_cast<char*>(REAL(x));
  long dl = Rf_xlength(x) * 8;
  std::ofstream OutFile;
  OutFile.open("/tmp/test.raw", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  OutFile.write(d, dl);
  OutFile.close();
}
```

R Code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(Rcpp)
library(dplyr)
library(fst)
fst::threads_fst(1)

sourceCpp("test.cpp")

x <- runif(134217728) # 1 gigabyte
df <- data.frame(x)

microbenchmark(test(x), write_fst(df, "/tmp/test.fst", compress=0), times=3)
Unit: seconds
                                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
                                      test(x) 6.549581 7.262408 7.559021 7.975235 8.063740 8.152246     3
 write_fst(df, "/tmp/test.fst", compress = 0) 4.548579 4.570346 4.592398 4.592114 4.614307 4.636501     3

file.info("/tmp/test.fst")$size/1e6
# [1] 1073.742

file.info("/tmp/test.raw")$size/1e6
# [1] 1073.742
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Benchmarking SSD write and read performance is a tricky business and hard to do right. There are many effects to take into account.

For example, many SSD's use techniques to accelerate data speeds (intelligently), such as DRAM caching. Those techniques can increase your write speed, especially in cases where an identical dataset is written to disk multiple times, as in your example. To avoid this effect, each iteration of the benchmark should write a unique dataset to disk.

The block sizes of write and read operations are also important: the default physical sector size of SSD's is 4KB. Writing smaller blocks hampers performance, but with `fst` I found that writing blocks of data larger than a few MB's also lowers performance, due to CPU cache effects. Because `fst` writes it's data to disk in relatively small chunks, it's usually faster than alternatives that write data in a single large block.

To facilitate this block-wise writing to SSD, you could modify your code:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('

  #include <fstream>
  #include <cstring>
  #include <iostream>

  #define BLOCKSIZE 262144 // 2^18 bytes per block

  long test_blocks(SEXP x, Rcpp::String path) {
    char* d = reinterpret_cast<char*>(REAL(x));

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(path.get_cstring(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    long dl = Rf_xlength(x) * 8;
    long nr_of_blocks = dl / BLOCKSIZE;

    for (long block_nr = 0; block_nr < nr_of_blocks; block_nr++) {
      outfile.write(&d[block_nr * BLOCKSIZE], BLOCKSIZE);
    }

    long remaining_bytes = dl % BLOCKSIZE;
    outfile.write(&d[nr_of_blocks * BLOCKSIZE], remaining_bytes);

    outfile.close();

    return dl;
    }
')
```

Now we can compare methods `test`, `test_blocks` and `fst::write_fst` in a single benchmark:

```r
x <- runif(134217728) # 1 gigabyte
df <- data.frame(X = x)

fst::threads_fst(1)  # use fst in single threaded mode

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  test(x, "test.bin"),
  test_blocks(x, "test.bin"),
  fst::write_fst(df, "test.fst", compress = 0),
  times = 10)
#> Unit: seconds
#>                                          expr      min       lq     mean
#>                           test(x, "test.bin") 1.473615 1.506019 1.590430
#>                    test_blocks(x, "test.bin") 1.018082 1.062673 1.134956
#>  fst::write_fst(df, "test.fst", compress = 0) 1.127446 1.144039 1.249864
#>    median       uq      max neval
#>  1.600055 1.635883 1.765512    10
#>  1.131631 1.204373 1.264220    10
#>  1.261269 1.327304 1.343248    10
```

As you can see, the modified method `test_blocks` is about 40 percent faster than the original method and even slightly faster than the `fst` package. This is expected, because `fst` has some overhead in storing column and table information, (possible) attributes, hashes and compression information.

Please note that the difference between `fst` and your initial `test` method is much less pronounced on my system, showing again the challenges in using benchmarks to optimize a system.

Comment: Thanks!  That's amazing. So by writing in smaller blocks, part of the output is kept on the cache by the OS.  I found that in your package, you used 16 KB?  Do you think that's the safest block size to use?

Comment: @thc: thanks! Yes, the `fst` format organizes it's data in 16 kB blocks which are the basic elements of compression and hashing. This small block size is used to facilitate random access (also for compressed data). Also, 16 kB fits nicely in the L1 CPU caches of most modern CPU's, so that helps the speed of processing data (compression / hashing). Then, multiple 16 kB blocks are combined and written to disk as a single chunk to optimize the IO speed further. The optimum number of 16 kB blocks used for these chunks was chosen separately for each column type.

Comment: @thc: for your use case, it's probably best to do some testing with different block sizes (identifier BLOCKSIZE in the example code) and see what happens :-)